# flutter app not running - Could not find aapt2-windows.jar

Tags: android, flutter, gradlew

i am new to flutter; i created a new project (nothing in code or files is changed) and when i try to run it, i get this error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not find aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows.jar
```

can anyOne tell what's wrong? i used to run my apps and there was no issue; i don't know what happened! weird thing is when i click on the link i can download aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows.jar manually. idk why gradlew can't resolve it.

p.s: my gradle.build is the default file; nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

you should try out the following two steps

1. Add mavenCentral() in build.gradle if missing

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```

2. update your minimum sdk version 16 to 21

```
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.jahid.testing_stackoverflow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Comment: @jahid-islam tnx for your response. i added the buildScript and updated minSdkVersion but i still get the same error message!

Comment: you should try with flutter clean and flutter run

Comment: are you used google() in buildScript and allprojects repository?

Comment: yes i tried that too. i upgrated my flutter now i face a lot of 403 forbidden errors so i think the issue is not sth that i did it's because of the google's sanctions against iran.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred when trying build android app, and off course it's related to gradle!

**Solution 1, if you are using android studio and lucky!:**

1. Open your flutter project android module as a separate project with a android studio.

[image: open as a separate project]

2. As project open, android studio suggest you update gradle, click update and waiting for downloading to finish, run project again, it should work now.

[image: suggestion dialog]

---

**Solution 2, if you are using android studio and don't lucky:**

If for any reason in the previous solution android studio didn't show you recommended dialog, as you open android module as a separate project, click on project structure button and set versions manually.

*Remember last version might not always working properly, so be wise!*

[image: project structure dialog]

---

**Solution 3, if you are not using android studio:**

You can also set these versions manually by going to following locations:

For setting `android gradle plugin version` go to `YOUR_FLUTTER_PROJECT\android\build.gradle` and changing:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
}
```

For setting `gradle version` go to `YOUR_FLUTTER_PROJECT\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` and changing:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```